# Error handling best-practices

Tags: rust

I've been fumbling through Rust's documentation trying to execute a simple esoteric example for my own educational benefit more than practicality. While doing this, I can't seem to wrap my head around how Rust's error handling is meant to be used.

The programming example I'm using is to write a function that runs a command in a shell. From the result of the command I want to retrieve `stdout` (as a `String` or `&str`) and know whether or not the command failed.

The [`std::process::Command`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) struct gives me the methods I want, but it seems that the only way to combine them is kludgy and awkward:

```
use std::process::Command;
use std::string::{String, FromUtf8Error};
use std::io::Error;


enum CmdError {
    UtfError(FromUtf8Error),
    IoError(Error),
}


// I would really like to use std::error::Error instead of CmdError,
// but the compiler complains about using a trait in this context.
fn run_cmd(cmd: &str) -> Result<String, CmdError> {
    let cmd_result = Command::new("sh").arg("-c").arg(cmd).output();

    match cmd_result {
        Err(e) => {
            return Err(CmdError::IoError(e));
        }
        Ok(v) => {
            let out_result = String::from_utf8(v.stdout);

            match out_result {
                Err(e) => {
                    return Err(CmdError::UtfError(e));
                }
                Ok(v) => {
                    return Ok(v);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let r = run_cmd("echo 'Hello World!'");

    match r {
        Err(e) => {
            match e {
                CmdError::IoError(e) => {
                    panic!("Failed to run command {:}", e);
                }
                CmdError::UtfError(e) => {
                    panic!("Failed to run command {:}", e);
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(e) => {
            print!("{:}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

In particular, the nested match blocks inside `run_cmd` seem really awkward, and the nested match blocks in `main` are even worse.

What I'd really like to do is be able to use a more general class of error than `FromUtf8Error` or `io::Error` which I can type convert into easily from either concrete type, but it doesn't appear the type system is designed in this way, so I had to use the crude `CmdError` as somewhat of a [union type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) instead.

I'm sure there's an easier way to do this which is more idiomatic, but I haven't found it from the documentation I've read so far.

Any [pointers](http://xkcd.com/138/) appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

Defining things like this is not a particularly neat thing at present; there are a few things you need to set up with your custom error type, but after you’ve done that things are a lot easier.

First of all, you will want to implement `std::error::Error` for `CmdError` (which requires `std::fmt::Display` and `std::fmt::Debug`), and then in order that `try!` can work automatically, `std::convert::From<std::string::FromUtf8Error>` and `std::convert::From<std::io::Error>`. Here are the implementations of those:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::string::FromUtf8Error;
use std::fmt;
use std::io;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum CmdError {
    UtfError(FromUtf8Error),
    IoError(io::Error),
}

impl From<FromUtf8Error> for CmdError {
    fn from(err: FromUtf8Error) -> CmdError {
        CmdError::UtfError(err)
    }
}

impl From<io::Error> for CmdError {
    fn from(err: io::Error) -> CmdError {
        CmdError::IoError(err)
    }
}

impl Error for CmdError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        match *self {
            CmdError::UtfError(ref err) => err.description(),
            CmdError::IoError(ref err) => err.description(),
        }
    }

    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&Error> {
        Some(match *self {
            CmdError::UtfError(ref err) => err as &Error,
            CmdError::IoError(ref err) => err as &Error,
        })
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for CmdError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            CmdError::UtfError(ref err) => fmt::Display::fmt(err, f),
            CmdError::IoError(ref err) => fmt::Display::fmt(err, f),
        }
    }
}
```

(The `description` method in the `Error` implementation could possibly return a string not based on the wrapped error, e.g. “failed to run command”. If one wants the details, they’ll still be there in `Error.cause()`.)

After implementing that lot, things are a lot easier because we can use [`try!`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html). `run_cmd` can be written thus:

```
fn run_cmd(cmd: &str) -> Result<String, CmdError> {
    let output = try!(Command::new("sh").arg("-c").arg(cmd).output());
    Ok(try!(String::from_utf8(output.stdout)))
}
```

Because `try!` uses the `From` infrastructure, this is all a lot simpler; the first line may return an `Err(CmdError::IoError(_))` (for `Command.output()` returns `Result<_, io::Error>`), and the second line may return an `Err(CmdError::UtfError(_))` (for `String::from_utf8(…)` returns `Result<_, FromUtf8Error>`).

Your `main` can also be somewhat simpler then, with the `err` branch not needing any further matching if you don’t care about the particular error; as it implements `fmt::Display` now, you can just use it directly.

Incidentally, in a format string, `{:}` should be written as `{}`; the `:` is superfluous if not followed by anything. (`{:?}` would work for showing `Debug` output, but you should prefer to use `Display` if it’s user-facing.)

Answer (score 4):

### How to do it in 2019

#### Question mark operator (`?`)

Rust now has the question mark operator that makes propagating errors easy. You can read about it in the very complete [chapter about recoverable errors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/second-edition/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) in the Rust book.

#### Easy error type definition

There are several crates on [crates.io](https://crates.io/) that make it easy to define custom error types without having to write all the boilerplate that you had to write before. 
One very easy way to declare zero-overhead error types is to use the [**`custom_error`**](https://crates.io/crates/custom_error) crate. I am the author of that crate.

#### Example: parsing the output of an external command

Combining the two points above, the example given in the question can be re-written in a very concise and readable way:

```
use std::string::FromUtf8Error;
use std::io;
use std::process::Command;
use custom_error::custom_error;

custom_error! {CmdError
    UtfError{source: FromUtf8Error} = "The command returned an invalid string: {}",
    IoError{source: io::Error} = "Unable to launch command: {}"
}

fn run_cmd(cmd: &str) -> Result<String, CmdError> {
    let out_bytes = Command::new("sh").arg("-c").arg(cmd).output()?.stdout;
    let out_string = String::from_utf8(out_bytes)?;
    Ok(out_string)
}

fn main() {
    match run_cmd("echo 'Hello World'") {
        Ok(res) => println!("{}", res),
        Err(e)  => eprintln!("{}", e)
    }
}
```